# What's the lowest level I can inject a mouse event into Qt 4.7?

Tags: c++, qt

I need to jolt my app with some mouse events, but I *really* want Qt to think they are coming from the end user at every level possible, yet it still needs to be *in* Qt.

Not sure where to look; it's a big API. :)

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about your requirement

Comment: I'm having an issue where I see (a very busy) GUI freezes under some versions of OSX. What is happening is that internal to OS X, the graphics color correction pipeline has a bug that shows up with very high update rates. They fixed this in 10.8, but earlier versions... they freeze. *However*, if you wave the mouse over the window, the stuck messages get flushed and the display unfeezes. I would like to try to inject regular mouse messages to cause the unsticking to happen in order to work around this. I don't know if it will work, but I'd like to try.

Comment: So this isn't something you'd do in Qt, it needs to be done at the level of OS X APIs.

Comment: Perhaps, but you can't be sure of that until you try. With Qt, you can install event filters (for instance, to modify tooltips) and they seem to be happening at a pretty deep level. Hey, I can hope. It beats another go at hacking fixes of Apple's bugs for them, [like I did here](http://fyngyrz.com/?p=921) - that kind of thing is tedious beyond all measure, sigh.